# How to make CSS Animation reverse on hover-out?

Tags: html, css, animation

I have an animation on my site which goes from *`width: 100px to 800px` when hover on*.

But when *hover out*, it just goes to the normal position with no animation.

How could I get it so the animation would go back on hover-out the same way it came on hover?

I only found solutions for transitions, but I need it for animation.

```
<div id="blackbox"/>
<div id="blacktxt">
Navigation
</div>
```

[See Here](http://jsfiddle.net/kZS62/1/)

Comment: you need to add for #blackbox (for example) {-webkit-transition:all linear 2s;}

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why not use transitions instead of animations? [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kZS62/4/)

```css
#blackbox {
    background: black;
    width: 100px; 
    height: 80px; 
    color: white; 
    text-align: center; 
    font-family: Times; 
    font-size: 20px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 100px;
    opacity: 0.5;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    transition: all 2s; /* Add this transition */
}

#blackbox:hover { /* Apply the new design on hover */
    opacity: 0.8;
    width: 800px;
}

#blacktxt {
    margin-top: 10px;
    height: 60px;
    transition: opacity 0.5s, width 5s;
    position: absolute;
    font-family: cursive;
    cursor: default;
}

#blacktxt:hover {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="blackbox">
    <div id="blacktxt">
        Navigation
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But can transitions be timed like animations?

Comment: Yes, using transition-timing-function. But I think this doesn't work in IE9.

Comment: But can transitions have keyframes like animations? Is there an answer to this question other than *use transitions*?

Comment: @Tamlyn I'm not sure animations will be the right choice here.. maybe give Ziad's plugin a try.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the additional features CSS animations provide over transitions, there is a fix to seamlessly reverse CSS animations using the vanilla javascript [Web Animations API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API) and the [playbackRate property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Animation/playbackRate).

Here is the code (note that you only have to specify one animation in css):

```js
let el = document.querySelector('.el');

// play animation on mouseenter
el.addEventListener('mouseenter', function () {
  
  // force animation again if already triggered
  el.classList.remove('animate');

  // hack trigger a DOM reflow to reinit animation
  void el.offsetWidth;

  //trigger animation
  el.classList.add("animate");

 }, false);

// reverse animation on mouseout
el.addEventListener('mouseout', function () {
 playReverse(el);    
}, false);


function playReverse(el) {
  let ani = el.getAnimations()[0];
  
  if(!ani) {
    return;
  }
  
  ani.playbackRate = -1;
  ani.play();
}
```

```css
.el {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: black;
  animation-duration: 6s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.animate {
  animation-name: transforms;
}

@keyframes transforms {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  100% {
   transform: translate(400px, 0);
  }
  
}
```

```html
<div class='el'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the [jQuery Reversible](https://github.com/ZiadJ/jquery.reversible) plugin for this. Its main advantage over CSS transitions is that it works on IE9 and older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of animation you can achieve it by transition itself

```css
#blackbox {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  transition: width 0.3s, height 0.3s;
}

#blackbox:hover {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

#blacktxt {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="blackbox"></div>
  <div id="blacktxt">Navigation</div>
</body>
</html>
```

By running this you could see the transition happened during hover and while hout-out it goes back to its initial state.